# setting cpu affinity of a process from the start on linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, taskaffinity

I want to set the cpu affinity of a process on linux when it is starting.

There are methods like sched_setaffinity and taskset, but they need the processid of the process. They may cause potential migration like a process was started on a core but after the  use of sched_setaffinity/taskset, they were migrated to another core.

What I want to do is to start a new process on a specific core from the beginning.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Often, the kernel is better than you to choose a core to run some task...

Comment: I am working on a checkpointing module which checkpoints a process.   I want to save the cpu-affinity information for this process and start this process from the last checkpoint with the same affinity.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`taskset` can be used both to set the affinity of a running process or to launch a process with a certain affinity, see

- [How to launch your application in a specific CPU in Linux (CPU affinity)?](https://web.archive.org/web/20200128140005/http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2010/09/23/how-to-launch-your-application-in-a-specific-cpu-cpu-affinity-in-linux/).
- [man page for taskset](http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset)

**Synopsis**

```
taskset [options] mask command [arg]...
taskset [options] -p [mask] pid
```

The below command will launch Google Chrome browser in CPU 1 & 2 (or 0 and 1). The mask is 0×00000003 and command is “google-chrome”.

```
taskset 0×00000003 google-chrome
```